# FileUtil.copyMerge deletes not just merged files?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm looking into the FileUtil.copyMerge method in the hadoop-core library, and although I'm no Java expert I have a sinking feeling that it does not remove *only* the files that have been copied and merged. I think it simply removes everything from a particular path, which means that if files have been added during the copy-merge, they will be removed too, even though they may not have been copy-merged.

Here is the relevant section from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c59af2fdf8f7f53117c626a895dab7fd78cf08ec/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java):

```
public static boolean copyMerge(FileSystem srcFS, Path srcDir,
                                FileSystem dstFS, Path dstFile,
                                boolean deleteSource,
                                Configuration conf, String addString) throws IOException {
  dstFile = checkDest(srcDir.getName(), dstFS, dstFile, false);

  if (!srcFS.getFileStatus(srcDir).isDirectory())
    return false;

  OutputStream out = dstFS.create(dstFile);

  try {
    FileStatus contents[] = srcFS.listStatus(srcDir);
    Arrays.sort(contents);
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      if (contents[i].isFile()) {
        InputStream in = srcFS.open(contents[i].getPath());
        try {
          IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, conf, false);
          if (addString!=null)
            out.write(addString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        } finally {
          in.close();
        }
      }
    }
  } finally {
    out.close();
  }


  if (deleteSource) {
    return srcFS.delete(srcDir, true);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The final `if (deleteSource)` statement is independent from what happens inside the `else if (srcFS.isFile(src))`, which to me indicates that once the top bit is done and `deleteSource` is set to `true`, it simply removes all files from `src` irrespective of whether they have been added post-copy-merge.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Erm ... this method is copy, not copyMerge

Comment: Ouch! I was being very lazy while copy-pasting. The implementations all look the same really... Sorry, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my interpretation correct?

I don't think so.  If anything goes wrong during the copy-merge stage, then the `copyMerge` call will terminate with an exception.  That happens before it gets to the delete stage.

Comment: It's not about exceptions though. If a new file arrives when it's just done copy-merging, then there is no exception to be thrown. Rather, it'll go to the final `if` and as far as I can tell remove everything in srcDir, which will include the new file, which has not yet been copy-merged causing data loss.